# Are these equation the same?

Tags: java

Hi I'm studying java in university and I have just done a piece of code which calculates BMI and it goes like this, num1 being Kilograms and num2 being Centimetres **((num1/num2)/num2)*10000;** when I showed my teacher this equation he told me it was incorrect and the correct one was **num1/((num2*num2)/10000);** When I tested both lines of codes I received the same result, but yet he told me I needed to prove that both lines are the same like AxB and BxA, but I haven't found a way to prove they are both the same but I do have an idea on how they'd be the same. My question is, are they both the same?

If I did 70 KG as weight and 175 CM as height it would say something on the lines of 22.9 (baring in mind this is with my equation). With my teachers one it would be the same. But he doesn't believe they are the same. This is my code:

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class apples {

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    String fsum; /* this is a variable declaration*/
    String sum; /* this is a variable declaration*/
    double answer; /* this is a variable declaration*/
    double num1, num2; /* this is a variable declaration*/
    String anything; /* this is a variable declaration*/
            Scanner Tahmid = new Scanner (System.in);/*Scanner Variable*/
    System.out.println("This program was created by Tahmid Ahmed on 01/10/2013\nThis program would allow you the user to be able to calculate your BMI");
    System.out.println("To continue please click enter");/*Output*/
    anything = Tahmid.nextLine();/*Input as a break*/
    fsum=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter weight in Kilograms (KG) "  ); /*Popup box to allow weight to be entered*/
    sum=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter height in Centimetres (CM) ");/*Popup box to allow height to be entered*/
    num1 = Double.parseDouble(fsum);/*Conversion of String into Double*/
    num2 = Double.parseDouble(sum);/*Conversion of String into Double*/

    answer = num1/((num2*num2)/10000);/*<<<<<<<<-----My teachers Equation*/ /*My Equation ---- >>>>>> ((num1/num2)/num2)*10000       */
    if (answer<=18){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total BMI levels are: " + answer, "You're underweight! Eat some more!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    else if(answer>=25){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total BMI levels are: " + answer, "You're overweight now bro! Eat Less!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);   }

    else if(answer<25) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total BMI levels are: " +answer, "You're the perfect weight! Stay that way :)", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}


}
```

}

Comment: This is more a math question than a programming one. Actually, there are cases, when a mathematically equivalent formula gives wrong result, while the other works flawlessly (think of integer overflow for example)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math.

Answer (score 2):

They are mathematically equivalent, but not equivalent in floating-point. Your teacher is trying to make the point that all the multiplications should take place before all the divisions, so that maximum precision is attained. The parentheses around `num2*num2` ensure that it is calculated first.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why multiplying first give you better precision?

Answer (score 1):

Just playing with the algebra, it's clear they're equivalent:

```
((num1/num2)/num2)*10000  ??  num1/((num2*num2)/10000)
((num1/num2) * (1/(num2)) * 10000   ??   num1 / (num2^2 / 10000)
(num1 / num2^2) * 10000  ??  num1 * (10000 / num2^2)
10000 * num1 / num2^2  ==  10000 * num1 / num2^2
```